# Java - Eliminating specific characters and whitespace in a string

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working with JTables and I've successfully fetched the contents of my table and placed them into a string array. I then concatenated every element of the array into a one string.

I kindly need assistance with striping out specific chars and whitespaces from the string which  is as follows:

tableDataAsString is:

```
[ABCD, EFGH, IJKL, null][MNOP, QRST, UVWX, null]
[YZAB, CDEF, GHIJ, null][KLMN, OPQR, STUV, null]
[WXYZ, ABCD, EFGH, null]
```

The above is what the last System.out.println prints. My code is as below:

```
     // Get table data as String
 public void getTableContent() {
     //System.out.println("x-x-x-x-x-x Get table content in string format has started x-x-x-x-x-x ");

     int nRow = getRowCount(), nCol = getColumnCount();

     Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];

     // For loops used to run thriugh rows and columns in order to fetch cell values
     for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
         for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol - 1 ; j++)
                tableData[i][j] = getValueAt(i,j);

     // Prepare string array which will contain cell values
     String tableDataAsStringArray[] = new String[tableData.length];

     // Write cell values into string array
     for (int i = 0; i < tableDataAsStringArray.length; i++ ) {
         tableDataAsStringArray[i] = java.util.Arrays.toString(tableData[i]);

         System.out.println("getTableContent() - Table data in row " + i + " of string array is: " + tableDataAsStringArray[i]);
     }


     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

     // Append all the cell values into a single string
     for(String s : tableDataAsStringArray) {
         builder.append(s);
     }

     String tableDataAsString = builder.toString();

     System.out.println("getTableContent() - tableDataAsString is: " + tableDataAsString);

     //System.out.println("x-x-x-x-x-x  Get table content in string format has ended x-x-x-x-x-x ");
 }
```

To be more specific I want to remove the [] and replace the null with a semicolon ();. So my ideal outcome after the replacements would be:ABCD,EFGH,IJKL;MNOP,QRST,UVWX;YZAB,CDEF,GHIJ;KLMN,OPQR,STUV;WXYZ,ABCD,EFGH

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The String class `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` method would replace specific characters with a new one. Is this what you're going for?

Comment: SO you wanted to replace `[,]` chars from your tableDataAsString ?

Comment: To be more specific I want to remove the [] and replace the null with a semicolon ();. So my ideal outcome after the replacements would be:ABCD,EFGH,IJKL;MNOP,QRST,UVWX;YZAB,CDEF,GHIJ;KLMN,OPQR,STUV;WXYZ,ABCD,EFGH

Answer (score 0):

```
myRedactedString = myString.replaceAll("[badchars]", "x");
```

Replace `badchars` with the actual characters you want to replace.  Replace `x` with what you want to replace them with, possibly the empty string. Remember to escape character like `[` according to the regex rules. Example:

```
myCompressedString = myString.replaceAll("[, \[\]]", "");
```

--- Edited to add

```
after = before.replaceAll("null", ";").replaceAll("[\[\] ]", "");
```

Please note that the space in the second replaceAll is required to eat the source spaces.